# Convert CamelCase to camel_case in MySQL

Tags: mysql, camelcasing, snakecasing

Is there a way to convert CamelCase to camel_case using only mysql? I know I can do it in php but I wanna be able to do it in mysql, because I need to convert millions of strings.

Comment: camel_case isn't CamelCase it's lower_dash_case

Comment: I think this is going to be really hard without 26 nested REPLACE statements, and one SUBSTRING statement

Comment: @VeNoMiS I really think I know that, but this way it's clearer.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html The docs contain a exampe of using REGEX / SUBSTRING / CONCAT to modify strings. You'll have to make a MySQL function probably. Look for the post by Umesh Shastry.

Comment: @Oli Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists replaceCamelCase $$
create function replaceCamelCase( p_str TEXT ) returns text
BEGIN
declare v_pos int;
declare v_len int;
declare cnt int;
declare tmp text;
declare ret text;

set v_pos=1;
set v_len=1+char_length( p_str );
set ret = '';
set cnt = 0;

if p_str REGEXP('[^_]') then
while (v_pos<v_len)
do
    set tmp = SUBSTR(p_str, v_pos, 1);

    if tmp REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]' = 1 then

        if cnt > 0 then
            set ret = concat(ret, '_');
        end if;

        set ret = concat(ret, lower(tmp));
        set cnt = cnt + 1;
    else
        set ret = concat(ret, tmp);
    end if;

    set v_pos = v_pos + 1;

end while;

else 
set ret = p_str;
end if;

RETURN ret;


end $$
```

User it like this:

```
SELECT replaceCamelCase(name) FROM `test` WHERE 1
```

Example input/output:

```
BlaTest
test_test
BaldieBal
TestStringCase
```

Output:

```
bla_test
test_test
baldie_bal
test_string_case
```

Comment: Awesome work @Oli, well done. I never thought this could be pulled off in MySQL. I also tested it and it's great.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated answer for 2023: you no longer need a stored function, instead you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) using a back-reference (`$1`) as the replacement value (which is not in the documentation, but it works), like so:

```sql
mysql> SELECT LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE('FooBarBaz', '([A-Z])', '_$1', 2, 0, 'c'));
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE('FooBarBaz', '([A-Z])', '_$1', 2, 0, 'c')) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| foo_bar_baz                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that I'm passing `2` to the 4th param of the function (StartPos) because we don't need to add an underscore in front of the first character. I'm passing `0` for unlimited matches to the 5th param, and `'c'` for case-sensitive matching.

Answer (score -1):

Knock yourself out - but see my comment above:

```
SELECT REPLACE('CamelCase', BINARY 'C','_c');
+---------------------------------------+
| REPLACE('CamelCase', BINARY 'C','_c') |
+---------------------------------------+
| _camel_case                           |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't think this is one of your finest answers.